# ASP.NET component in ColorBox closes after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, colorbox

I have a asp.net component inside a ColorBox window, and after choosing a country in 
Dropdownlist auto postback happens(to automatically set states) and ColorBox closes, so how to stop ColorBox from closing during postback?

I want ColorBox only to close when user clicks exit button or save button

heres the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#hdfContainsPrint').val() == 'True') {
        window.location = document.location.href;
    }

    var $close = $('#cboxClose').appendTo('#cboxWrapper').css({ width: 22, top: 1, right: 1, zIndex: 9999, position: 'absolute' }).hide();

    $("#<%=btnSearch.ClientID%>").colorbox({ inline: true, overlayClose: false, opacity: 0.8, href: "#inline-view", scrolling: false,
    });

    $('#colorbox').appendTo('form');

    $("a[id=btnNewDok]").bind("click", __doc_create_envoke);
```

Markup:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="inline-view">
       <uc1:myComponent ID="componentID" runat="server" Visible="true" />
    </div>            
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autopostback of the dropdown performs a form POST action, which forces the page to refresh. To prevent this, you must use an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) alternative. For example, you can place the dropdown inside an `UpdatePanel`. The `UpdatePanel` will execute asynchronously without refreshing the page and thus maintaining your ColorBox.

An example of how to use a `DropDownList` with `AutoPostBack` inside an `UpdatePanel` can be found [here](http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/ajax-tutorials/using-updatepanel-triggers-in-asp-net-3-5/).

Comment: Gotta love Microsoft's attempt at AJAX - making it work non-asynchronously given that it means "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML". :/